# calculated column (texte + date ) in sharepoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, vba

I wanna create a calculated column in sharepoint 2013 that contains value of 2 columns, a text column and date ,
Example calculated `column = [column 1 (text)]+[column 2(date )]`

I tryed this :

```
=[Colonne1]&" "&TEXTE([Colonne2], "mmm-dd-yyyy")
```

but I have a syntax error ,

thank you for the help

Info:my format language is French

Comment: Can you share error?

Comment: my syntaxe exact is : =[Adresse]&" "&TEXTE([Créé], "mmm-dd-yyyy"),
here is the error :

Désolé... Nous avons rencontré un problème 


La formule contient une erreur de syntaxe ou n'est pas prise en charge.

english : 

Sorry ... We have encountered a problem

The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.

Comment: Try to break the formula up and test each part. Make a calculated column with just `TEXTE([Colonne2], "mmm-dd-yyyy")` and see if that works?

Comment: Try the same thing in Excel (with same datatypes applied to test-columns) and see if it works

Comment: it doesn't work with just TEXTE([Colonne2], "mmm-dd-yyyy"), but if i put this syntax : =DATE(ANNEE(Créé);MOIS(Créé);JOUR(Créé)) i had a result like:
01/06/2016,  only the date my question is to put in calculated column a text + date ?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I think the problem is that you are mixing data types (text & date) so I would try first converting the date to text and then combining the results (text & text).

Comment: maybe so how can we convert date to text i try this TEXTE([Colonne2], "mmm-dd-yyyy") but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post on how to convert your date to a string.

[how-to-convert-date-field-in-single-line-of-text-using-calculated-columns](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45774/how-to-convert-date-field-in-single-line-of-text-using-calculated-columns)

I hope that helps.